# How to find the list of fonts is being used in the word document(.docx) uploaded in the SharePoint 2013 Library?

Tags: document-library, document, word

I have a requirement to find the list of fonts is being used in the word document(.docx) uploaded in the SharePoint 2013 Library? how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of fonts in a word file is stored in an XML file called `fonttable.xml`. To get this file, you need to convert the word file into a package (zip file) and parse the contents of `fonttable.xml`.

Note: You need to add 2 references: `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` and `WindowsBase.dll` to your project for handling word processing.

Following code handles getting the file from document library using CSOM and reading the file to get the fonts and stores them in a generic list.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://siteUrl");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents").GetItemById(itemID);
ctx.Load(listItem);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = listItem.File;
ClientResult<Stream> data = file.OpenBinaryStream();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(data.Value, false);
var fontTable = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.OpenXmlPackage.Package.GetPart(new Uri(@"/word/fontTable.xml", UriKind.Relative));
XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
XmlNodeList xmlnode;
int i = 0;
Stream fs = fontTable.GetStream();
xmldoc.Load(fs);
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("w:fonts");
var childNodes = xmlnode[0].ChildNodes;
List<string> allFonts = new List<string>();
for (i = 0; i <= childNodes.Count - 1; i++)
{
allFonts.Add(childNodes[i].Attributes[0].Value);
}
ctx.Dispose();
```